# Hide Image button from some rows in Gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I have added an image button in the template field of the gridview. The gridview contains 20 rows. In all the rows, the image button is being added. Now, if i wish to hide the image button from some rows, what should i do?

I cannot remove from the gridview else that would go away from all rows.

Please guide

Let me know for any query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make use of `RowDataBound` Event avaialbe with the GridView where you can hide the control you want for the given row.

```
void grv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
      if(condition)
      {
       ImageButton imgBtn= (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("mybuttonid");
       imgBtn.Visible = false;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In RowDataBound Event:

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
     ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgbtnImage")).Visible = false; 
 }
```